# Data transformation using sed

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a file like:

```
A
B
C
D

E
F
G
H

I
J
K
L
```

and I want it to come out like

```
A,B,C,D
E,F,G,H
```

I'm assuming I'd use `sed`, but actually I'm not even sure if that's the best tool.  I'm open to using anything commonly available on a Linux system.

In `perl`, I did it like this ... it works, but it's dirty and has a trailing comma.  Was hoping for something simpler:

```
$ perl -ne 'if (/^(\w)\R/) {print "$1,";} else {print "\n";}' test
A,B,C,D,
E,F,G,H,
I,J,K,L,
```

Answer (score 8):

Set the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR) to paragraph mode ([`-00`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-0*[_octal/hexadecimal_])) and then split each record on any remaining whitespace:

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print join("," => split), "\n"' test
```

---

Add [`-l`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-l*[_octnum_]) to enable automatic newlines (but make sure it comes before `-00`, because we want `$\` to be set to the value of `$/` *before* modification):

```
$ perl -l -00 -ne 'print join("," => split)' test
```

---

Add [`-a`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-a*) to enable autosplit mode and implicitly split to `@F`:

```
$ perl -l -00 -ane 'print join("," => @F)' test
```

---

Swap out `-n` for [`-p`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-p*) for automatic printing:

```
$ perl -l -00 -ape '$_ = join("," => @F)' test
```

Comment: I came up with `perl -00nE 'chomp; s/\s+/,/g; say' file` to prevent double spacing the output.

Comment: @GillesQuenot Because it will set the output record separator to the same value as the input record separator if it's omitted, and we don't want that. So, we have to set it first, before modifying `$/`.

Comment: @ikegami yup, it would work `perl -l -00 -ane 'print join ",", @F'`

Comment: Adding `-F$"\n"` would support lines with space.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=""; FS="\n"; ORS="\n"; OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1' file
```

---

I see the gawk manual says this:

> If RS
>          is set to the null string, then records are separated by blank lines.  When RS is set to the null string, the newline character always acts as a field separator, in addition to whatever value FS may have.

So we don't actually need to specify FS to get the desired output:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=""; ORS="\n"; OFS=","} {$1=$1} 1' file
```

Comment: You also don't need to set ORS since `\n` is the default - `awk -v RS= -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1'`

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` could do it,

```
$ xargs -n4 < file | tr ' ' ','
A,B,C,D
E,F,G,H
I,J,K,L
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing newlines with `sed` is a bit complicated (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1251999/6770384)). It is easier to use `tr` for the newlines. The rest can be done by `sed`.

The following command assumes that `yourFile` does not contain any `,`.

```
tr '\n' , < yourFile | sed 's/,*$/\n/;s/,,/\n/g'
```

The `tr` part converts all newlines to `,`. The resulting string will have no newlines.
`s/,*$/\n/` removes trailing commas and appends a newline (text files usually end with a newline).
`s/,,/\n/g` replaces `,,` by a newline. Two consecutive commas appear only where your original file contained two consecutive newlines, that is where the sections are separated by an empty line.